# binding nested foreach with different models in knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, foreach

I am newbie to KnockoutJS. I am trying to bind different models to nested foreach 
but I stuck up while binding models through jquery. Here is my fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/pKCNf/**
It shows object in alert box on click of button but not binding it to inner foreach.

Jquery:

```
    var arr = new Array();

    function viewModel(id, title, desc, name) {

        var self = this;
        self.messageId = ko.observable(id);
        self.title = ko.observable(title);
        self.description = ko.observable(desc);
        self.name = ko.observable(name);            
        self.commentList = ko.observableArray([]);

    }

    function commentViewModel(newsId, firstName, lastName, comment) {
        var self = this;
        self.newsId = ko.observable(newsId);            
        self.FirstName = ko.observable(firstName);
        self.LastName = ko.observable(lastName);
        self.comment = ko.observable(comment);
    };

    function simpleBinding() {
        var self = this;
        self.businessMessages = ko.observableArray([
            new viewModel(1,'ABC','kdshfkh','John Mathew'),
            new viewModel(2,'MNP','kdshfkh','John Mathew')
        ]);


        self.getComment = function (cmt) {

                    var vm = new viewModel();
                    var cmtArray = new Array();
                    var entry = new commentViewModel(18, 'John', 'Mathew', 'Hiii');
                    cmtArray.push(entry);
                    vm.commentList(cmtArray);
                    alert(vm.commentList());
                    $('.nestedArea').slideToggle();
                    console.log(vm.commentList());
        };

    }

    var modelBind = new simpleBinding();
    ko.applyBindings(modelBind);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your Fiddle, I've made a few updates to get you further along - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/pKCNf/1/).

The `self.getComment` function was creating a new `viewModel` rather than using the one which the UI is bound to. So this changed it to:

```
self.getComment = function (cmt) {
    //cmt is the "viewModel" instance which "clicked"                    
    var entry = new commentViewModel(18, 'John', 'Mathew', 'Hiii');
    cmt.commentList.push(entry);

    $('.nestedArea').slideToggle();
    console.log(vm.commentList());
};
```

Also, the bindings in you HTML (only shown in the Fiddle) had a case-mismatch in the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields.

Given all that, you should be able to continue, however, you may want to look at making the models more encapsulated. The `getComment` function should really be in the `viewModel` object as it is trying to update the properties of that instance - normal OO stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are almost there. http://jsfiddle.net/pKCNf/2/

```
<div data-bind="foreach:businessMessages">
  <p data-bind="text:messageId"></p>
   <p data-bind="text:title"></p>
   <p data-bind="text:description"></p>
   <p data-bind="text:name"></p>
  <button data-bind="click: addComment">Add Comment</button>
  <div class="nestedArea" data-bind="foreach:commentList">
    <p data-bind="text:newsId"></p>
    <p data-bind="text:firstName"></p>
    <p data-bind="text:lastName"></p>
    <p data-bind="text:comment"></p>
  </div>
</div>

function viewModel(id, title, desc, name) {
  var self = this;
  self.messageId = ko.observable(id);
  self.title = ko.observable(title);
  self.description = ko.observable(desc);
  self.name = ko.observable(name);            
  self.commentList = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.addComment = function() {
    self.commentList.push(new commentViewModel(18, 'John', 'Mathew', 'Hiii'));
  }
}

function commentViewModel(newsId, firstName, lastName, comment) {
  var self = this;
  self.newsId = ko.observable(newsId);            
  self.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
  self.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
  self.comment = ko.observable(comment);
};

function simpleBinding() {
  var self = this;
  self.businessMessages = ko.observableArray([
    new viewModel(1,'ABC','kdshfkh','John Mathew'),
    new viewModel(2,'MNP','kdshfkh','John Mathew')
  ]);
}

var modelBind = new simpleBinding();
ko.applyBindings(modelBind);
```